# VBA To Iterate RecordSet

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013, recordset

I am using VBA to iterate a recordset, and when I use the `RecordCount` feature it returns 8 (which is accurate) - but when I use `Debug.Print` to print out the variable on each pass, only the first 3 variables are processed.

Why does this syntax stop short?

```
Set rs = Db.OpenRecordset("Select statement here)", dbOpenDynaset)
Debug.Print rs.RecordCount
'This prints 8
 With rs
  If Not .EOF And Not .BOF Then
     .MoveLast
     .MoveFirst
     Do While Not .EOF
        fakca = .Fields(0).Value
            Debug.Print fakca
            'only prints the first 3 in the table?
        .MoveNext
     Loop
  End If
End With
```

The `.RecordCount` will print 1, 2, 3101, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9 - but the `Debug.Print fakca` will only print 1, 2, 3101 and it stops

Comment: `The .RecordCount will print 1, 2, 3101, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9` - There is no way RecordCount is going to print that. Are you sure you have pasted correct code? Also, why you are doing movelast and then movefirst?

Comment: @PankajJaju - sorry, I mis-spoke, the .RecordCount prints 8 - and those are the 8 numbers it should print in ascending order.

Comment: Can you double check if Debug.Print line is before or after .MoveNext

Comment: @PankajJaju - the Debug.Print fakca in the OP is exactly where it is in my source code

Comment: When you say the program stops, do you mean it ends or do you see some sort of error message?

Comment: @PankajJaju - it ends - no error message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158177/discussion-between-pankaj-jaju-and-bellhopbydayametuercoderbynigh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
With rs
    If Not .EOF Then
        .MoveFirst
        Do While Not .EOF
            fakca = .Fields(0).Value
            Debug.Print fakca
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End If
End With
```

I think that the missundernstanding comes from the usage of this:

```
If Not .EOF And Not .BOF Then
     .MoveLast
     .MoveFirst
```

Thus I have avoided it. What is the idea of using `.BOF`?

Comment: I've had issues before with recordsets errorring without a `.BOF` check, so that's not entirely alien to me - IMO the `.MoveFirst` is no-op, and the OP's `.MoveLast`+`.MoveFirst` combo is no-op as well, or should be. IOW use `.MoveNext` inside the loop, simple as that. No need to explicitly jump around the recordset all over the place.

Comment: `.MoveLast` + `.MoveFirst` is something I often use when I need to use `.RecordCount` on a DAO recordset (to make sure the full recordset is loaded before evaluating the count). But that requires it to get called before calling `.RecordCount`, which is not the case here, so I don't understand either.